# How to use 2- or 3-letter :substitute commands?

Tags: substitute

`:help change.txt` mentions 2- or 3- letter :substitute commands, such as `:sg`, `:sgn` and so on. I am guessing that these `:s[xx]` correspond to flags, but am not sure how to use them.

For example, I would think that `:%sg/foo/bar` would substitute all matches of `foo`, including multiple occurences on the same line. However, that commands gives me an error --- "trailing characters".

What is the appropriate syntax for `:s[x[x]]`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Actually the behavior of the substitution command `:s` if you don't provide any arguments is to repeat the last substitution you did. So if you have a line

```
foo Foo foF
```

And use `:s/f/X/` you will get

```
Xoo Foo foF
```

Now if you use `:s` (without any argument) you will reapply the same command and get as a result:

```
Xoo Foo XoF
```

The 2 and 3 letters substitution commands work the same but adding some flags at the end of the original substitution. So now if you have the previous line and use `:sgi` you will get the equivalent of `:s/f/X/gi` which will result in

```
Xoo Xoo XoX
```

That explains why you get `E488 Trailing characters` the short substitutes commands don't take an argument as they only apply the last `:s` command.

Answer (score 1):

statox has given a complete answer. I tried to find this in the documentation, searching for `:h :sg`, `:h :sgn`, etc. But that only provided a table of 2-letter and 3-letter substitute commands.

It turns out that the behavior in statox's answer is documented much higher up in the help file. To find it, refer to `:h :&` or the paragraph after `:h :s`. Quoting from the help (emphasis mine):

> :[range]s[ubstitute] [flags] [count]
> :[range]&[&][flags] [count]
>
> Repeat last :substitute with same search pattern and
> substitute string, but without the same flags.  You
> may add [flags], see |:s_flags|.
> Note that after `:substitute` the '&' flag can't be
> used, it's recognized as a pattern separator.
> **The space between `:substitute` and the 'c', 'g',
> 'i', 'I' and 'r' flags isn't required, but in scripts
> it's a good idea to keep it to avoid confusion.**